# How to pass Parameters in a nested Function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, prop

Our code currently has a function that calls a toast message popup while saving an object to the database.

```
export function addAnimal(animalObject) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    showToastNotification(() => {
      return addAnimal(animalObject);
    }, dispatch);
  };
}


function showToastNotification(handleToastSave, dispatch) {    
  return handleToastSave()
    .then(() => {
      showMessage("this was a success")(dispatch);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      showMessage("Something went wrong!")(dispatch);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      saveMode(false)(dispatch);
    });
}
```

My question is I want to pass a `message` string as a parameter to the showToastNotification like this:

```
export function addAnimal(animalObject) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    showToastNotification(("successfully added animal") => {
      return addAnimal(animalObject);
    }, dispatch);
  };
}

function showToastNotification(message, handleToastSave, dispatch) {    
  return handleToastSave()
    .then(() => {
      showMessage(message)(dispatch);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      showMessage("Something went wrong!")(dispatch);
    })
    .finally(() => {
      saveMode(false)(dispatch);
    });
}
```

This doesn't work. I'm not super familiar with how the fat arrow in this function works. Would it be possible to pass a prop to showToastNotification?

Answer (score 2):

You're putting the string where the parameters of the callback would be, instead of as the first argument to the actual showToastNotification function. Just move it to the right place:

```
showToastNotification("successfully added animal", () => {
  return addAnimal(animalObject);
}, dispatch);
```

Comment: do you know where's the best place I can find resources about fat arrow functions like this? I still don't 100% understand the syntax

Comment: If you Google "ES6 arrow function" you can find plenty. But it's fairly simple. Where you would previously create an anonymous function by doing `function(param1, param2, param3) { /* Code here */ }` you can now write it like `(param1, param2, param3) => { /* Code here */ }` Instead. If you just want the function to be a single line that returns the result of that line, you can remove the {} and the word "return" if you like; `(p1, p2, p3) => p1+p2+p3` will add the parameters and return the sum, for instance. In arrow functions, `this` refers to the outer scope instead of the function scope.